# How to access the currently selected item within Wicket Palette

Tags: wicket

I am trying to override certain features of the Wicket Palette. I have attached a picture of what i am trying to accomplish with Palette. Basically in addition to the select-item-clickbutton-moveToRight functionality of Palette, I also want to know which item has been selected before it is moved. When I select an item in either of the panels and click on a View button, I should be able to display an html page related to the currently selected item from the Palette.
Right now, the button is placed out of the Palette code and as long as I can get the ID of the selected element, I will be able to accomplish my objective.
I am stuck at the point where I need to know which item has been selected within the palette.

Here's what I have tried so far:
1. Adding an onclick listener to the choicesComponent using the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior

final Palette classFormMapping = new Palette("formsPalette", new ListModel(selectedFormsList),
                formsList, new CustomObjectChoiceRenderer(), 8 , false ){

```
        @Override
        protected void onBeforeRender() {
            super.onBeforeRender();
            getChoicesComponent().add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick"){
                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    System.out.println("REACHED HERE"+ getFormComponent());
    /*
                 * The code reaches here for each click but I am unable to know which item was selected */
                }
            });

            }

    };
```

2. Adding a Recorder component to the Palette with an "onclick" listener.
   This listener does not get called at all.

final Palette classFormMapping = new Palette("formsPalette", new ListModel(selectedFormsList),
                formsList, new CustomObjectChoiceRenderer(), 8 , false ){

```
        protected Recorder newRecorderComponent() {
            Recorder recorder = super.newRecorderComponent();
            recorder.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    System.out.println("reached record on click ");


                }
            });
            return recorder;
        }

    };
```

[Trying to create this palette with a custom button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AegE5.jpg)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Palette.java javadoc explains how to "Ajax-ify" it: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/529db58c413861677f7ff6736f9363edf42ae85a/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/palette/Palette.java#L52-L71

But this won't help you because the selection is done at the client side first and then Wicket is notified:
https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/529db58c413861677f7ff6736f9363edf42ae85a/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/palette/palette.js#L118-L127

You need either to register your own JS event listener for 'change' event before the Wicket one or monkey-patch palette.js to override `Wicket.Palette.updateRecorder()` function.

Comment: Hi @martin-g, Thanks for your reply. 
By registering an JS event listener for change event, did you mean the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour("onchange") listener? I had already tried that but its called only after I click on the Add button to move it to the selected list.

Comment: Code attached here:
`recorder.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Override
     protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      Iterator<FormTemplate> selectedColumns = getSelectedChoices();
      List<FormTemplate> selectedEventTypeAttributes = new ArrayList<FormTemplate>();
      while(selectedColumns.hasNext()){
       FormTemplate eventTypeAttribute = selectedColumns.next();
       selectedEventTypeAttributes.add(eventTypeAttribute);
      }
      
     }
    });`